# When Current column and Previous column > 0, then do this

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from table;
+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | cnta | cntb |  cntc | 
+------+-------------+-------+
4         0      1      2   
3         2      3      0
2         1      0      1   
1         3      2      2
```

I would like to compare two sequential rows (current column and previous column) and if they are both greater than 0, I'd like to sum the results of the sequential rows.

this is what I tried and failed:

```
SELECT
         g1.id,
(case        
    When g2.cnta > 0 and g1.cnta > 0 then g1.cnta ELSE 0) End as cnta + 
(case        
    When g2.cntb > 0 and g1.cntb > 0 then g1.cntb ELSE 0) End as cntb +     
(case        
    When g2.cntc > 0 and g1.cntc > 0 then g1.cntc ELSE 0) End as cntc 
 
FROM table g1 INNER JOIN table g2 ON g2.id = g1.id+ 1;
```

the final output I'm trying to get is like this (if current column and previous column > 0, then  current column1 + etc ) :

```
id    totalcnt
4        1   
3        2
2        2
1
```

How can I fix my query? or can I get alternative approach as a solution, please?

** I forgot to mention that there are no NULL values in my table. Only 0s and positive integers.

Comment: *the final output I'm trying to get is like this* Does shown desired outpuit matches shown sample data **completely**? If not then adjust. If matched then explain in details how does each output value is calculated. And provide the output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: yes, I calculated the output manually myself.  Mysql version : 5.7.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your last row of the result is not to be empty, try this:

```
SELECT  
t1.id, 
(
CASE WHEN t1.cnta>0 AND t2.cnta>0 THEN t1.cnta ELSE 0 END  
+  
CASE WHEN t1.cntb>0 AND t2.cntb>0 THEN t1.cntb ELSE 0 END
+
CASE WHEN t1.cntc>0 AND t2.cntc>0 THEN t1.cntc ELSE 0 END
) AS cValue    
FROM 
table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.id=t1.id-1;
```

OR if you really want it to be empty, you can use a subquery

```
SELECT 
t1.id,
IFNULL(
(
SELECT 
(
CASE WHEN t1.cnta>0 AND t2.cnta>0 THEN t1.cnta ELSE 0 END  
+  
CASE WHEN t1.cntb>0 AND t2.cntb>0 THEN t1.cntb ELSE 0 END
+
CASE WHEN t1.cntc>0 AND t2.cntc>0 THEN t1.cntc ELSE 0 END
) 
FROM 
table1 t2 WHERE t2.id=t1.id-1)
,'') AS cValue 
FROM table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks, Asgar, but your queries didn't give me the correct results. when current row and previous row compared, ONLY IF both  > 0, then sum of the current row. and do this for all columns to get the all columns. that's what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I have tried the same data you posted in my laptop. I have posted the query only after checking your data.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, after checking it again, yes, it works. thanks a lot.

Comment: My eyes... Please, take a look at an SQL pretty printer, or even just make some judicious use of your space bar to format your SQLs so they're readable

Comment: @CaiusJard, still learning to answer :) . 
I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       (t1.cnta * t2.cnta > 0) * t1.cnta
     + (t1.cntb * t2.cntb > 0) * t1.cntb
     + (t1.cntc * t2.cntc > 0) * t1.cntc totalcnt
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.id = t2.id + 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=48f296035e95bf4c7331427e82c25619

`t1.cntX * t2.cntX` is NULL if at least one value is NULL, is zero if at least one value is zero, and is 1 if both values are not zero/NULL.